# Error with a getJSON call in jquery with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following code in html, I cannot get the Function call back of JSON get call. Down is the code in controller. Please Help

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $().ready(function() {
         $("#CuitDespachante").typeWatch({ highlight: true, wait: 500, captureLength: -1, callback: finished });
    });

    function finished(txt) {
        $.getJSON('/Documentacion/GetDatosDespachantes', { cuitDespachante: txt },
                            function (data) {
                                alert('You typed: ');
                            }
        );

    };
</script>

public ActionResult GetDatosDespachantes(string cuitDespachante)
        {
            cuitDespachante = cuitDespachante.Replace("-", "").Replace("_", "");
            DepositarioFielWS.DepositarioFielWebService ws = new DepositarioFielWS.DepositarioFielWebService();
            var res = ws.GetDespachante(cuitDespachante);
            if (res.Licencia.CodigoLicencia == DepositarioFielWS.CodigoLicencia.Ok)
            {
                DepositarioFielWS.Despachante desp = new DepositarioFielWS.Despachante();
                desp.Cuit = res.Despachante.Cuit;
                desp.Nombre = res.Despachante.Nombre;


                var respuesta  =new
                {
                    cuit = desp.Cuit,
                    nombre = desp.Nombre

                };
                return Json(respuesta);
            }
            else
            {
                var respuesta = new
                {
                    cuit = cuitDespachante,
                    nombre = "Imposible Realizar Consulta"

                };
                return Json(respuesta);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error or exception?

Comment: I dont get an error or exception, I just down not call the funtion

Comment: Then the problem is probably the routes. Use firebugs "net" tab to confirm that (or you will see the error instead).

Comment: If I use this function finished(txt) {
         $.getJSON('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Documentacion/GetDatosDespachantes")%>', { cuitDespachante: txt }, $('#nombreDespachante').html("Prueba"));

    }
I see the html change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to add this in the response of the controller, Something new in ASP.NET MVC 2

```
 return Json(respuesta,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: thx for this information. god, am i happy i found your answear.. i tried so long and never got a response back ;-)